# How to convert a PDF file to a TXT file using an autocmd?

Tags: pdf, vim, pdftotext

When I drag a PDF file in a VIM Tab I want to convert it to a TXT file using pdftotext. (I've installed pdftotext on my disk)

To do this I added this cmd in vimrc:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.pdf silent %!pdftotext -layout -q -eol unix "%"
```

In vim 7.4 it worked fine. It opened the PDF file in TXT format.
Now in vim 8.1 it doesn't work as expected. It converts the PDF and creates the TXT file on my disk (in the same PDF directory) without opening it.

What I want is to create the TXT file always in the same directory "D:\temp", close the PDF file and open the TXT file.

I tried this but without success:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.pdf silent %!pdftotext -layout -q -eol unix "%" | :let myfile = "D:\\temp\\".expand("%:r").".txt" | :bd | :exe "tabe ".myfile
```

Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

How can I create the TXT file in "D:\temp", close the PDF and open the created TXT file in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It converts the PDF and creates the TXT file on my disk

It's not `vim`'s fault, it's `pdftotext`'s. For quite some time has been behaving this way. You need to force it to write to stdout by appending `-` which means "output file is stdout":

```
autocmd BufReadPost *.pdf silent %!pdftotext -layout -q -eol unix "%" -
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

It makes more sense, IMO, simply to replace the buffer contents.

```
let g:Pdf2Txt = 'pdftotext -layout -q -eol unix %:p:S -'

augroup Pdf2Txt | au!
    autocmd BufReadCmd *.pdf execute expandcmd('silent read ++edit !'..g:Pdf2Txt)
    autocmd BufReadCmd *.pdf 1delete_
    autocmd BufReadCmd *.pdf setfiletype text
    autocmd BufReadCmd *.pdf setlocal buftype=nowrite
augroup end
```